# Необязательный ввод через input()

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

Допустим, что User должен ввести какую-либо информацию, через enter (каждая строчка - отдельная переменная). Их может быть любое количество, зависит от Пользователя.
В идеале, чтобы когда была нажата комбинация клавиш, можно было перестать вводить и выполнялись следующие команды.

Comment: Что конкретно у тебя не получается в поставленной задаче? Прикрепляй свои попытки

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю, вам подойдет выход из цикла по пустому инпуту

(Если пользователь просто жмет `Enter`, питону дается ''. При этом условии делаем `break`)

```
while True:
    value = input('Введи слово, чтобы закончить просто нажми Enter ')
    if value == '':
        break
    else:
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Когда человек закончит вводить текст он просто в пустой строчек нажмёт Enter, И цикл закончиться. Весь текст сохраняеться в массиве 'all_text'

```
all_text = []
while True:
    val = input("Ввод текста>>> ")
    if val=="":
        break
    else:
        all_text.append(val)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]